# Difference between the tailboard and boot lid.

Tags: automotive-engineering

What is difference between the **tailboard** and the **bood lid**? Can you show me where each part is?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tailboard would be the name of the opening panel found at the rear on a pick-up type vehicle, while a boot lid is the name for the panel that closes the boot or trunk. An SUV has the rear panel called a door and if the rear window opens it is likely to be called a hatch - also hatch-back.